# Chart.js Set line chart borderColor based on the value

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am drawing a line chart using chart.js to display system status (up or down).

I want to use the same series and display in red when status is down and green when status is up.

Chart fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dilani_m/gk59jsud/18/)

dataset options:

```
"datasets": [
      {
        "label": "System",
        "borderColor": "#66ff00",
        "backgroundColor": "#66ff00",
        "data": data,
        "fill": false,
        "tooltipName": "System",
        "negative": false,
        "pointRadius": 0,
        "lineTension": 0
      }
    ]
```

Output:
[image]

Expected :

[image]

How can I achieve this? Is there any callback I can add to dataset borderColor to set each point colour based on value?